# Is three routers better than two for WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, interference

I have a five room, 114m^2 (1200square feet), single story apartment.
I have two routers set up. One working as a proper router and one functioning as a pure [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)  (it has wired access itself). It is very clear from careful measurement that I definitely need two routers as opposed to one to get good WiFi coverage in the whole apartment.

I have set up these routers in opposite ends of the apartment (It would perhaps have been better to have a single router in the center of the apartment, but that is not possible for several practical reasons).

Now, I already own a third router (hardware identical to the WAP) that I could set up as a second WAP, potentially forming a fairly equilateral triangle of routers. The third router would also have wired access itself.

Will I get even better WiFi reception with a third router? 
Or will the routers interfere with each other, and perhaps even make the reception worse?
(It is a big apartment house, so there are already plenty of WiFi routers in the vicinity)

The hardware in question is an *ASUS RT-N56U Dual-band Wireless-N Gigabit Router Router* as main router and two *Netgear WNDR3700v1* (running *DD-WRT*) as WAP. So all routers have dual-band, support 11n, and are fairly high-end. They are all configured to auto-select appropriate channels.

Comment: Are you noticing that some parts of your apartment are still not getting good coverage/signal?

Answer (score 1):

Two is plenty for 1200 sq. ft. If there is a lot of interference in your apartment, then you may add another. However, if the routers are on different channels, then they should not interfere with one another.

Comment: But if they are on different channels, can he move around the apartment (with his mobile for example) without losing WiFi connection?

Comment: That is a good question. I am curious myself, so I just asked SU. http://superuser.com/questions/359918

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if I were you, I would:

1. draw a rough top-view-map of the house
2. get Wifi signal analyzer software ([for android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5mYXJwcm9jLndpZmkuYW5hbHl6ZXIiXQ..), [iphone](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=com.agranados.wifianalyzer) or [laptop](http://www.xirrus.com/Products/Wi-Fi-Inspector))
3. create a heat map for the wifi signal.

You might also try [Meraki WiFi Mapper service](http://meraki.com/products/wireless/wifi-mapper).

I have apartment of more than 140 meters and it is covered with just one ADSL router placed at the middle, but signal is weak at the both ends.